# Generate python code from a sympy expression?

Tags: python, sympy

**The Question**:
Given a sympy expression, is there an easy way to generate python code (in the end I want a .py or perhaps a .pyc file)?  I imagine this code would contain a function that is given any necessary inputs and returns the value of the expression.

**Why**

I find myself pretty frequently needing to generate python code to compute something that is nasty to derive, such as the Jacobian matrix of a nasty nonlinear function.

I can use sympy to derive the expression for the nonlinear thing I want: very good.  What I then want is to generate python code from the resulting sympy expression, and save that python code to it's own module.  I've done this before, but I had to:

1. Call str(sympyResult)
2. Do custom things with regular expressions to get this string to look like valid python code
3. write this python code to a file

I note that sympy has code generation capabilities for several other languages, but not python.  Is there an easy way to get python code out of sympy?

I know of several possible but problematic ways around this problem:

1. I know that I could just call evalf on the sympy expression and plug in the numbers I want. This has several unfortuante side effects:

   - dependency: my code now depends on sympy to run.  This is bad.
   - efficiency: sympy now must run every time I numerically evaluate: even if I pickle and unpickle the expression, I still need `evalf` every time.
2. I also know that I could generate, say, C code and then wrap that code using a host of tools (python/C api, cython, weave, swig, etc...).  This, however, means that my code now depends on there being an appropriate C compiler.

**Edit: Summary**
It seems that sympy.python, or possibly just str(expression) are what there is (see answer from smichr and comment from Oliver W.), and they work for simple scalar expressions.

That doesn't help much with things like Jacobians, but then it seems that sympy.printing.print_ccode chokes on matrices as well.  I suppose code that could handle the printing of matrices to another language would have to assume matrix support in the destination language, which for python would probably mean reliance on the presence of things like numpy.  It would be nice if such a way to generate numpy code existed, but it seems it does not.

Comment: Depends on the type of functions you're generating with Sympy. Most functions have a direct equivalent in the standard module `math`, some are also represented in `numpy` or `scipy.special`. If you don't want to depend on Sympy, you'll have to copy over the string representation to your actual file anyway, similar to the way you're doing it now (the string representation is usually valid python code already, given `math` is imported). You could automate that with a function that writes a valid python file that has that (sympy)function, but then it won't be a very generic export-function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function you are looking for to generate python code is `python`. Although it generates python code, that code will need some tweaking to remove dependence on SymPy objects as Oliver W pointed out.

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> x = sp.Symbol('x')
>>> y = sp.Symbol('y')
>>> print(sp.python(sp.Matrix([[x**2,sp.exp(y) + x]]).jacobian([x, y])))
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
e = MutableDenseMatrix([[2*x, 0], [1, exp(y)]])
```

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind having a SymPy dependency in your code itself, a better solution is to generate the SymPy expression in your code and use [`lambdify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) to evaluate it.  This will be much faster than using [`evalf`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#evalf), especially if you use numpy.

You could also look at using the printer in [`sympy.printing.lambdarepr`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/printing/lambdarepr.html) directly, which is what `lambdify` uses to convert an expression into a lambda function.

Comment: can you please give an example in code, what that would look like?